# OpenCV Overly Two Images

Tags: opencv

I am new to opencv and I have tried to overly the origanal image with the detected contours in a single window, but I am having difficulty with it. Is it possible to overly this two images in one window. If so, how?

```
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 20;
int max_thresh = 20;
RNG rng(12345);

// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void* );

/** @function main */
 int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  // Load source image and convert it to gray
  src = imread( "image18.jpg", 1 );

  // Convert image to gray and blur it
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
   blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(31,31) );

  // Create Window
   char* source_window = "Source";
  namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( source_window, src );

   createTrackbar( " Canny thresh:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
   thresh_callback( 0, 0 );

   waitKey(0);
   return(0);
   }

/** @function thresh_callback */
void thresh_callback(int, void* )
{
  Mat canny_output;
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

  // Detect edges using canny
  Canny( src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );
  // Find contours
  findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

  // Draw contours
  Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
  for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
     {
       Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
       drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 0.5, 1, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
      }

   // Show in a window
   namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( "Contours", drawing );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can **draw  contours right** on the **source image**, i.e. instead of this:

```
Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
```

use original image:

```
drawing = src;
```

(though using local variables and passing matrix by reference as parameter would be a better style)

Comment: It's probably safer to call `cv::Mat drawing = src.clone();` so that it won't modify the original image.